# Como crio uma lista para possíveis respostas no python?

Tags: python-3.x, lista, input, if, else

Eu queria fazer uma lista para possíveis respostas do usuário ao input, por exemplo:

```
nom = str(input('Você gosta de mim? '))

lista = ['sim','claro','obvio']


if nom == lista:
  print('obrigado, bom saber')
else:
  print('Que pena')
```

Se o usuário digitasse uma das palavras que estão naquela lista iria imprimir a mensagem `"Obrigado, bom saber"`.

Quando eu colocava uma das palavras que estão na lista aparecia a outra mensagem `"que pena"`.

Como fazer assim com uma lista ou tem que ser fazendo as possíveis respostas no `if`?

Comment: `if nom in lista:`

Comment: Vlw cara, me ajudou bastante ✌️

Comment: aqui `nom = str(input('Você gosta de mim? '))` não precisa usar `str()` pois `input()` já retorna string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quiser testar se um elemento está contido numa sequencia use o operador [`in`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations).
`x in s` retorna `True` se `x` é membro de `s`, caso contrário retorna `False`.

[`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) retorna uma cópia da string os caracteres alfabético em minúsculo. É necessário para converter a entrada do usuário em minúsculo pois operadores de comparação e pertinência em Python são sensíveis ao caixa(se é maiúscula ou minúscula) do caractere.

O retorno da função [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#print) é string não sendo necessário a conversão com [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#func-str).

Se a intenção da comparação é apenas retornar um de dois valores sem realizar processamento pode-se usar uma [expressão condicional](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) do tipo `x if C else y` onde se a condição `C` for `True` retorna `x` caso contrário retorna `y`.

```
p = 'Você gosta de mim? '
r1 = 'obrigado, bom saber'
r2 = 'Que pena'
opts = ['sim','claro','obvio']
#Se a entrada do usuário em minusculas estiver em opts retorna r1 senão retorna r2
resp = r1 if input(p).lower() in opts else r2
print(resp)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
nom = str(input('Você gosta de mim? '))

lista = ['sim','claro','obvio']


if nom in lista:
  print('obrigado, bom saber')
else:
  print('Que pena')
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
nom = input("Você gosta de mim?")

nom = nom.lower()

lista =["sim", "claro", "obvio"]

if nom in lista:
    print("Obrigado bom saber")

else:
    print("Que pena")
```

Modifiquei algumas coisas, por exemplo:

o `str()` ele não é crucial, o próprio python considera como string.

Também acrescentei o `.lower`, pois, caso digitasse alguma letra maiuscula ou minuscula ele iria para o `else`.

Answer (score 1):

Para condições simples, você pode usar o `if` ternário do Python:

```
print('obrigado, bom saber') if input('Você gosta de mim? ') in ['sim','claro','obvio'] else print('Que pena')
```

Algumas pessoas consideram que esse é o jeito "Pythônico" de fazer. Outros dirão que prejudica a legibilidade.

Como o seu objetivo parece ser aprender a usar o `if`, fica aí mais uma possiblidade.

No entanto, em um programa real, **sempre trate todas as entradas do usuário**.